# How to check if "s" permission bit is set on Linux shell? or Perl?

Tags: linux, perl, file-permissions

I am writing some scripts to check if the "s" permission bit is set for a particular file.
For example - permissions for my file are as follows-

```
drwxr-s---
```

How can I check in bash script or a perl script if that s bit is set or not?

Comment: `ls -l`, and search the results for `s`

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. But I have too many files in my directory to do this, plus I do not want to do process this big result as well. I know the file name, just want a quick way to check that

Comment: You can run `ls -l` on a single file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're using perl, then have a look at [perldoc](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/-X.html):

```
-u  File has setuid bit set.
-g  File has setgid bit set.
-k  File has sticky bit set.
```

So something like:

```
if (-u $filename) { ... }
```

Answer (score 1):

non-perl options

## Using `stat`

```
#!/bin/bash
check_file="/tmp/foo.bar";
touch "$check_file";
chmod g+s "$check_file";

if stat -L -c "%A" "$check_file" | cut -c7 | grep -E '^S$' > /dev/null; then
    echo "File $check_file has setgid."
fi
```

Explanation:

- Use `stat` to print the file permissions.
- We know the group-execute permission is character number 7 so we extract that with `cut`
- We use `grep` to check if the result is `S` (indicated setgid) and if so we do whatever we want with that file that has setgid.

## Using `find`

I have found (hah hah) that find is quite useful for the purpose of finding stuff based on permissions.

```
find . -perm -g=s -exec echo chmod g-s "{}" \;
```

Finds all files/directories with setgid and unsets it.